# Is there a difference in speed between using const and static const inside a function?

Tags: c, performance, static, constants

In C, what is the difference between `static const` and `const` **inside a function**?

For instance, take the given code examples:

```
void print_int(int x) {
  assert( x < 5 && x > -5 );
  const int i[9] = {
    -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
  };
  printf("%i", i[x + 4]);
}
int main() {
  print_int( 1 );
  return 0;
}
```

Versus:

```
void print_int(int x) {
  assert( x < 5 && x > -5 );
  static const int i[9] = {
    -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
  };
  printf("%i", i[x + 4]);
}
int main() {
  print_int(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Would the generated assembly be optimized better if I used `static const` instead of `const`, or would the output be the same for both examples? Oh, these examples assumes that all optimizations have been turned off as the compiler could efficiently optimize both to result in the same output.

Comment: With optimizations, it will probably be the same either way.

Comment: When you compiled both, which had the shorter assembler output?

Comment: The question is too broad. And completely wrong targeted, comparing apples and pears. Only clear point is: the generated code will definitively not be the same. Pleas read about the semantics of `static` and `auto`.

Comment: @Jashaszun you're probably right about that. I forgot about optimizations, but what about with optimizations off.

Comment: @Olaf Elaborate. I know what static is. This is more of a question about efficiency, and last time I checked, `static const` and `const` are pretty much the same when it comes to actually running the program.

Comment: Only your compiler can tell. E.g gcc and friends have `-S` as an option to produce the assembler.

Comment: @JensGustedt and Martin James -- Should've thought about doing that before posting the question... whoops, but I don't have access to a compiler right now... Thanks

Comment: @Isaiah - In the first case, the lifetime of `i` is limited to the lifetime of `print_int`, whereas in the second the lifetime of `i` is the same as the lifetime of the program (and would be initialized once at program startup).  The second form is not re-entrant or thread-safe, but given that `i` is meant to be read-only, I don't think it's an issue.  Whether it makes a difference in runtime is an open question.

Comment: No, they are not. Read about persistence, for example, but also thread-safety and initializer. An `auto const` for instance can be initialized with actual argument values, as `auto` are created for each entry into the block (roughly!). I'll leave it as a minor task to determine how `static` behaves here. The `const` is actually a minor aspect, as it is just a promise of the programmer. C is not C++!

Comment: @Olaf -- So you're saying its legal to do this: `const int z = func_param;`? Where `func_param` is an int provided to a function?

Comment: For non-argument values, another difference is when the function is declared `inline`.  Although, LTO might be allowed to optimize away duplicates.

Comment: `static const int i[9]` is created once at compile time.  `const int i[9]` is created each time the function runs or created once at compiler time or ... (compiler dependent on how well it optimizes this code.)

Comment: Sure, if that is in a _block_ (i.e. inside a function - direct or indirect). It is basically the same as for a `const` argumentwhen the actual value is passed to it (Note: function arguments are basically the same as local variables of that function which are initialized with the values passed - however, allocation is done a bit earlier by the caller).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would the generated assembly be optimized better if I used `static`
>   `const` instead of `const`, or would the output be the same for both
>   examples?

No, assembly would not be the same, at least assuming [x86 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) and corresponding ISA. The objects of *static storage duration* are initialized before program's startup. The objects of *automatic storage duration* are managed within *stack frame*, that is instanized per function. They may also be stored directly in CPU registers if compiler decides so.

There will be no significant performance difference between these two examples, since I/O `printf()` function is most time consuming.